# converting a mixed dictionary to data frame

Tags: python, pandas

After extracting data from url in JSON, I got something like  this:

```
abc = {"data":[{ "nome": "Paulo", "idade": 27, "sexo":"M", "RG":"77732-5", "e-mail":"paulo@qualquer.com", "status":"ativo"},
               { "nome": "Ford", "idade": 45, "sexo":"M" ,"RG":"73332-5", "e-mail":"ford@qualquer.com", "status":"ativo"},
               { "nome": "Andre", "idade": 52, "sexo":"M" ,"RG":"66732-5", "e-mail":"andre@qualquer.com", "status":"afastado"},
               { "nome": "Kilian", "idade": 38, "sexo":"F", "RG":"55532-5", "e-mail":"kilian@qualquer.com", "status":"ativo"}]}
```

I need to transform to a dataframe like this:

```
data
nome    idade   sexo    RG  e-mail          status
Paulo   27  M   77732-5 paulo@qualquer.com  ativo   
Ford    45  M   73332-5 ford@qualquer.com   ativo
Andre   52  M   66732-5 andre@qualquer.com  afastado
kilian  38  F   55532-5 kilian@qualquer.com ativo
```

I have tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame from dict(abc)
```

and I got:

```
                                            data
0  {'nome': 'Paulo', 'idade': 27, 'sexo': 'M', 'R...
1  {'nome': 'Ford', 'idade': 45, 'sexo': 'M', 'RG...
2  {'nome': 'Andre', 'idade': 52, 'sexo': 'M', 'R...
3  {'nome': 'Kilian', 'idade': 38, 'sexo': 'F', '...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is what `.json_normalize` does e.g. `df = pd.json_normalize(abc['data'])`

Comment: I've never seen that `from` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame` function :

```
import pandas as pd

abc = {"data":[{ "nome": "Paulo", "idade": 27, "sexo":"M", "RG":"77732-5", "e-mail":"paulo@qualquer.com", "status":"ativo"},
               { "nome": "Ford", "idade": 45, "sexo":"M" ,"RG":"73332-5", "e-mail":"ford@qualquer.com", "status":"ativo"},
               { "nome": "Andre", "idade": 52, "sexo":"M" ,"RG":"66732-5", "e-mail":"andre@qualquer.com", "status":"afastado"},
               { "nome": "Kilian", "idade": 38, "sexo":"F", "RG":"55532-5", "e-mail":"kilian@qualquer.com", "status":"ativo"}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(abc["data"])
print(df)
```

Comment: I also tested the suggestion of @jqurious, worked fine too. Thank you!